# Ordering of SelectionChanged and MouseLeftButtonDown events for a listbox

Tags: wpf, listbox, mouseevent, selectionchanged

I have handled SelectionChanged and MouseLeftButtonDown events on WPF listbox. I need to ensure that SelectionChanged event is fired before MouseLeftButtonDown event.

Though the events do occur in desired order but is there any way to enforce that?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can't you just call the `MouseLeftButtonDown` method from the `SelectionChanged` one to achieve what you want?

Comment: No. In view containing the listbox, I do some handling based on selection change. And the MouseLeftButtonDown event is handled in other helper class for initiating the context for drag-drop handling.

Comment: I think what you can do to ensure that your `MouseLeftButtonDown` is fired AFTER `SelectionChanged` is call the method `SelectionChanged` from your `MouseLeftButtonDown`, but then you should handle your `SelectionChanged` as both events...:  
private void MouseLeftButtonDown(object o, MouseDownEvent (whatever it is) event) { SelectionChanged(this, event); }

private void SelectionChanged(object o, SelectionEvent(whatever it is) event) 
{ 
     // do selection changed events  
     // Check if MouseLeftButtonDown is down really and call event MouseLeftButtonDown 
}